# The model FlatPage is already registered

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to work my way through Practical Django Projects. It seems to be a bit old, but I've manage to convert the code up to this point.

At this point the book would like me to change my models.py to be this:

```
class SearchKeyword(models.Model)
    keyword = models.CharField(maxlength=50, core=True)
    page = models.ForeignKey(FlatPage, edit_inline=models.STACKED,
                             min_num_in_admin=3, num_extra_on_change=1)
```

I know that this is now done in the admin.py instead. So my models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage

class SearchKeyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    page = models.ForeignKey(FlatPage)

    class Admin:
        pass

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.keyword
```

And the admin.py I've created now looks like this:

```
from search.models import SearchKeyword
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage

class SearchKeywordInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SearchKeyword
    extra = 3

class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = FlatPage
    inlines = [SearchKeywordInline]

admin.site.register(FlatPage, FlatPageAdmin)
```

When I load the Admin page, I receive:

```
AlreadyRegistered at /admin/

The model FlatPage is already registered

Exception Value:The model FlatPage is already registered
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to unregister it first as the app itself ships with an `admin.py`

```
admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, FlatPageAdmin)
```